# Problem with unixodbc unmet dependencies

Tags: apt, package-management, dependencies

On Ubuntu 18.04 I am trying to install the following packages

```
apt-get install bison wget openssl libssl-dev libasound2-dev libc6-dev libxml2-dev libsqlite3-dev libnewt-dev libncurses5-dev zlib1g-dev gcc g++ make perl uuid-dev git subversion libjansson-dev unixodbc-dev unixodbc-bin unixodbc autoconf libedit-dev
```

but I get the following error

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 unixodbc : Conflicts: unixodbc-bin (< 2.3.7) but 2.3.0-4build1 is to be installed
```

I tried remove the existing unixodbc-bin package and trying the main command above again but still getting the same error.

Anyone knows how to solve this?

Comment: Please run `sudo apt-get update` and add output of `apt-cache policy unixodbc-dev unixodbc-bin unixodbc` to the question.